# Pandas Compute Unique Values per Column as Series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to collect simple stats for each column in a Pandas DataFrame. Collecting the number of non-empty data points was no problem:

```
valueCountSeries = mydataframe.count()
```

However I would like to join this information with a series containing the number of unique values.  At the moment I compute this value as follows:

```
header = list(mydataframe.columns.values)
unique = [(c, mydataframe[c].nunique()) for c in header]
```

So I have unique but not as a Pandas series.
Essentially I want a series so I can reach the next step:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([valueCountSeries, uniqueCountSeries])
```

Is there a Pandas-esque way to get unique as a Series so I can join the result with valueCountSeries in a new DataFrame?

Adapting the result from below. Given the following matrix:

```
    A  B  C  D
 0  4  0  3  3
 1  3  1  3  2
 2  4  0  0  nan
 3  2  1  0  1
 4  1  0  1  4
```

I want to compute:

```
   count  nunique
A      5        4
B      5        2
C      5        3
D      4        4
```

Thanks!

Comment: An example DataFrame would really help here, IMO it's unclear how you're hoping to merge these (what the result should be).

Comment: Apologies, I should have included some data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
#    A  B  C  D
# 0  4  0  3  3
# 1  3  1  3  2
# 2  4  0  0  4
# 3  2  1  0  1
# 4  1  0  1  4
dct = {func.__name__:df.apply(func) for func in (pd.Series.nunique, pd.Series.count)}
print(pd.concat(dct, axis=1))
```

yields

```
   count  nunique
A      5        4
B      5        2
C      5        3
D      5        4
```

Comment: Thanks! Very nice.  I am just loving how Pandas makes this look as easy as it should be.